# Multi-language bot using LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to create a multilanguage bot by detecting the language and selecting the proper set of LUIS keys and strings. My problem is, that my LuisDialog serializes itself and the MakeRoot method is not being called anymore.

My code (roughly):

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
 {
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var languageData = DetectLanguage(activity); // here I have the keys, strings etc.

        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(languageData));
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

I've tried with the intermediate dialog, which selects the language and `context.Forward` everything to the LuisDialog, but I'm struggling with managing that. If this is a good strategy, I can share more code. I'm also considering scoreables.

Comment: Add your RootDialog implementation please. Switching between LUIS apps can be done "quite easily" by setting AppId / Secret on the fly

Comment: My Root(Luis)Dialog has hundreds of lines in few base classes, can you tell me which part of RootDialog do you have in mind? I'm setting up the keys in the `base` constructor in LuisDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If your need is about switching the language of your LUIS Dialog at its start

You have to make a method to get each LUIS parameter by language and as you know the language with your `DetectLanguage`, choose the right ones.

Then pass them to your LuisDialog like the following:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var languageData = DetectLanguage(activity); // here I have the keys, strings etc.

        var luisService = new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute("yourLuisAppIdGivenTheLanguageData", "yourLuisAppKeyGivenTheLanguageData", domain: "yourLuisDomainGivenTheLanguageData"));
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(luisService));
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

And your RootDialog shoud look like this:

```
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public RootDialog(params ILuisService[] services) : base(services)
    {
    }
```

---

#### If you have a more complex project

We implemented a complex project allowing language switch at any time. Due to this possibility, activity's locale field could not be fully trusted even if you override it on the beginning of its processing.

The strategy is the following:

- Detect user's language in MessagesController's `Post` method, for every incoming message
- Store the user language in bot state (userData) when it's changing

Then:

- When displaying a text, get the value in the right language using userData
- When using a language specific tool like LUIS, get the right parameter using userData

You will need an intermediate RootDialog to handle this LUIS language switch, and you have to complete your LuisDialog after every detection (or to check the language before every MessageReceived on your LuisDialog).

Comment: Right now I'm doing exactly that (in the base class of RootDialog, which derives from LuisDialog) :) The problem is when the user writes a new message, I want to detect the language again, but my RootDialog instance is not created from scratch but rather deserialized and the constructor is not being called with my new `ILuisService`. Maybe I messed sth up in RootDialog and it's hanging in `context.Wait(MessageReceived)` forever instead of finishing?

Comment: Finishing each part of the LuisDialog with `context.Done()` is crucial here. We spent another couple of hours figuring out the dialog flow, but your strategy works, thanks :)

Comment: Great news, glad it helped